# Dynamic creation of table for web service response in html js

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the code for displaying `webservices json` response using `li`,`ul` tags dynamically it works fine but i need the same for table using `tr`,`td` the main thing to be noted is i need to save the `onclick` data here which is `data(doc1)` .help please thanks in advance

```js
  ul = $('#mydemo1');
          ul.html(null);
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) 
            {
             
             var doc1 = result[i];
            
           li = $('<li/>').html(doc1.Name).data(doc1);
           li.append($('<br/>'));
             
              li.append($('<hr>'));
              ul.append(li);
        
            }
```

```html
<ul id="mydemo1" style="text-align:left;"> </ul>
```

Comment: Not clear with what exactly you want.. :(

Comment: @AkshayJ result[i] contains the json response from webservice that contains employee names by using <li> i am printing the list of employee name also if i click on particular employee name i can able to save the detail data(doc1) which is further used in the application.its all working fine but i need the <table> implementation for the above which helps in good look and feel

Comment: Check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var tableelement= $('#mydemo1');                   //where mydemo1 is the id of some table in DOM


           for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                tableelement.append(createRow(result[i]));
           }

    function createRow(rowObject) {                              //dynamically adding rows to the Table where each row contains the name

        var trElement = "<tr>";
        trElement += "<td>" + rowObject.Name + "</td>";

        return trElement;
    }
```

Comment: thank you but i need to pass the name to next procedure or function so i need to store it in my html like what i have done in my question data(doc1)

Comment: It was just an example to solve your problem..Hope it helped you:)Accept it if it did help you ;)